# How do I pass a nested array of numbers as a command-line argument to a Node.js program and get is as an Array?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

The problem is that when you pass a command-line argument is passed as a string.

So when I run this `node index.js [[1,2],[2,3]]`

I am getting that in the `process.argv`

```
[
  '/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin/node',
  '/Users/user/node/index.js',
  '[[1,2],[2,3]]'
]
```

I can make a parser for that but I am trying to avoid that.

Is there a way to do that or I am abusing the arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arguments are passed as `string`, so you can't avoid it. You don't need to make a parser since that's a valid `JSON`

```
const arr = JSON.parse(process.argv[2])
```